# What exactly is the difference between My.Computer.FileSystem and System.IO.File

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, namespaces, coding-style

There is a lot of duplication of functions in the `My.Computer.FileSystem` and `System.IO.File` namespaces.

So what exactly is the difference between:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(source, dest, True)
```

and:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(source, dest, True)
```

Is there a performance difference? What is everyone's opinion on which which has the edge on read-ability? I personally use the `My.Computer` Namespace but that is just habit now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My.* is simply a set of facade-pattern classes implemented for VB.NET that encompass common System.IO* (and other) operations. There is a *very* tiny performance hit since you're going through an extra layer of abstraction but you have to decide if it's worth optimizing for that. I would suggest using whichever way makes sense to you and others in your shop.

If you examine the code for `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile` with .NET Reflector you will see that the method wraps many System.IO classes such as File and Directory and especially the File class' Copy, Move and Delete methods. Snippet:

```
'lots of other code snipped out for brevity and to show the use of System.IO classes...

Directory.CreateDirectory(FileSystem.GetParentPath(str))

   'snip

    If 
       ' snip
    Else
        File.Delete(str)
        File.Move(path, str)
    End If
Else
    File.Move(path, str)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's just me 'in my shop' so I can decide on what I like, but I was kind of interested in people's preferences.

Comment: JIT compilation makes even the "tiny performance hit" even less likely to be noticeable. I don't use the `My` class very much just for consistency reasons, but there's **absolutely nothing** wrong with using it if you find it convenient. That's the whole point, to speed development in common cases.

Comment: @Cody: Agreed on all counts. I edited and added the qualifier `very` to tiny per your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually nothing.

`My.Computer` was added to VB as a more convenient and understandable abstraction layer to underlying functions. Some of it's methods add new functionality which in my opinion would be the only time you would use it over `System.IO.File`.

An example where `My.Computer` would add functionality over `System.IO.File` is the [Network.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, wherein it has the ability to show a dialog to the user:

> If showUI is set to True, a dialog box
>   appears that shows the progress of the
>   operation; the dialog box contains a
>   Cancel button that can be used to
>   cancel the operation. The dialog box
>   is not modal, and therefore does not
>   block user input to other windows in
>   the program.

If you've already used `System.IO.File` in places I'd highly recommend against using `My.Computer` over it for consistency reasons. Namely, don't go around mixing calls to methods in `My.Computer` and `System.IO.File`, stick to one namespace!

Comment: “`My.Computer` was added to VB for beginners” – nonsense. That was never the stated use. Rather, it’s a *convenience layer* and nothing speaks against using it. It’s a bit unfortunate that some functionality is exactly duplicated though.

Comment: The fact that it abstracts functions for the user makes it a key item for beginner usage. It's not *just* a convenience layer so much as it provides extra functionality for certain methods over `System.IO.*`. I never meant my statement about beginners to be such a direct statement as I wrote it.

Comment: See my edited answer, hope this conveys the point a little bit better.

Comment: "virtually nothing" except that My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText inserts a 3 byte BOM at the beginning of the file, and system.io.file does not.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete
```

and

```
FileSystem.DeleteDirectory
```

method, there is quite an important difference.

Using

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete
```

a 'System.IO.IOException' will be thrown if the directory isn't empty. However, with

```
FileSystem.DeleteDirectory
```

the default action is to go ahead and delete the file unless you include an addidional parameter

This is from [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127970(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Public Shared Sub DeleteDirectory ( directory As String,   onDirectoryNotEmpty As DeleteDirectoryOption
> )
>
> Parameters directory
>
> Type: System.String Directory to be deleted.
> onDirectoryNotEmpty
>
> Type:
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption
> Specifies what should be done when a directory that is to be deleted contains files or directories. Default is DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents.

The other option is to specify DeleteDirectoryOption.ThrowIfDirectoryNonEmpty

There are also other differences, but this one, to me stands out a mile.

Answer (score 1):

The `My` namespace is a VB.Net construct which is intended, in part, to be a bridge between VB6 and .Net APIs.  These methods will tend to have VB6 semantics + look and feel.

If you're a VB6 user transitioning to .Net I would use these methods as they will be closer to the behavior you are expecting.  Otherwise I would stick with the standard .Net APIs of `System.IO.File.Copy`

**EDIT**

Several people have questioned if I'm mistaking the `My` namespace for the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.  I'm not.  The `My` namespace is a lot of things but **one** item it does is wrap certain calls into methods that forward into `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.  For example if you type the following code into a VB.net project

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(source, dest)
```

It will result in the following set of events

- A call to `MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile` will be embedded in the application
- The types `MyProject` and `MyComputer` will be generated into the assembly
- The `MyComputer` type simply derives from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer`
- Hence the `FileSystem.CopyFile` method resolves down to `FileSystemProxy.CopyFile` which simply forwards to `FileSystem.CopyFile`

Comment: “to be a bridge between VB6 and .Net APIs” – really? I think you’re confusing this with the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. Two things speak against your theory: ① the namespaces was added in *later versions* of VB.NET, and ② it doesn’t replicate the VB6 functionality particularly closely (except for `My.Forms`).

Comment: @Konrad I'm fairly certain I'm correct on this.  Under the hood the `My.Computer.FileSystem` calls get generated into the target assembly and they forward to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.  You can verify this with reflector

Comment: @Jared Even string comparison (`"a" = "b"`) emits code that relies on `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, that’s not an argument.

Comment: @Konrad see my editted answer.  Uses of `My.Computer.FileSystem` do forward to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem` which in part is intended as a compatibility layer for VB6 users.

Comment: @Jared Doesn’t `My.Computer.FileSystem` really forward to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem`, which is a *distinct* class from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem`? Can’t verify this now but this is the way I remember it and from the MSDN this makes more sense. The latter is indeed part of the compatibility layer while the former is a later introduction as part of the `My` namespace support layer.

Comment: @Konrad, those 3 types confuse me all the time.  Give me a sec

Comment: @Konrad yes the `My.Computer.FileSystem` eventually forwards into `M.VB.FileIO.FileSystem`. I was under the impression that both types though were a part of the compatibility layer.  The `FileIO.FileSystem` methods in particular

Answer (score 0):

Here's a difference that caused by app to malfunction:

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText inserts a 3 byte BOM (EF BB BF) at the beginning of the file, and system.io.file does not.

Thus, I replaced My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText with system.io.file.WriteAllText and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

With System.IO.File.Delete there is indeed a difference as compared to My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile:

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(a_file) throws a FileNotFoundException if a_file doesn't exist, whereas System.IO.File.Delete(a_file) does not.

System.IO.File.Delete only throws a DirectoryNotFoundException if the path included in a_file does not exist.