# Random access files at clean VB.NET way

Tags: vb.net

After working some time in VB.NET I would like to get rid of Microsoft.VisualBasic dependencies.
Since with text files and string manipulation goes easy here I don't know what to do.

Is it possible to write equivalent code in VB.NET without using Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace and how this code should look like?

```
Dim fnum As Integer = FreeFile()
FileOpen(fnum, "Setup\myadmin", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Shared, Len(idstruct))
FilePut(fnum, idstruct, 1) 'structure data to file in record 1
FileClose(fnum)
```

Comment: What does the structure of `idstruct` actually look like?  Does it contain all fixed length strings, or integers, or variable length strings, or a combination?  Do you need the new code to be compatible with the old file format, or are you willing to accept a new file format?

Comment: Why not just abandon the random access file, too, then?  Go with XML maybe?...

Comment: Hi Steve, Idle. I would like to keep old files with data. That change I will do somewhere later but now I still have different kind of programs written in older versions of MS basic which uses that same files (like QB4.5 for DOS:)

Comment: Data is mixed, strings of fixed-length.

Comment: @user973238 If you want to keep the file format, it's best just to stick with `FileOpen`/`FilePut`.

Comment: @Dominic, If there is no other way I would keep my old codes. Additional problem is that such code is in NET unacceptable slow. But for one record only is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I sympathise with your desire to remove all references to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, and as much as I think that doing so has value, sometimes it's just not worth the trouble.  The namespace does contain some useful tools which are not easily reproduced without it.

For instance, the `TextFieldParser` comes to mind.  It allows you to easily read CSV and fixed-width files.  There is no other class like it in the .NET framework.  So, is it worth it to reinvent the wheel just so that you don't reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace?  I would argue that it's not worth it.

While it would be possible to reproduce the behavior of `FileGet` and `FilePut` using `FileStream` and the `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, `BinaryReader`, and `BinaryWriter` classes, it's probably not worth all the trouble.  The `FileGet` and `FilePut` methods are provided specifically for backwards compatibility, so if compatibility with old systems is your goal, as much as it pains me to say it, using `FileGet` and `FilePut` is an appropriate solution.

However, some of this advice hinges on the type of data.  If, for instance, the structure only contains fixed width strings, that would be very easy to duplicate with the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, or with the `TextFieldParser`.  Or, if it contains just integers, perhaps it will be easy to reproduce with the `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`.

However, even if you can easily reproduce the logic using other non-VB-only classes, doing so doesn't gain you anything.  In fact, your code will be more complicated and it will be less self-documenting.  When you see code using `FileGet` and `FilePut`, not only is it easy to tell what is being done, but it is also obvious that it is for backwards compatibility.  If you replace them with your own logic, the necessity for backwards compatibility would not be obvious without adding comments to the code.

If you don't like looking at them, which I can certainly understand, it may be worth wrapping them in a wrapper class.  For instance, you could create a data-access style class with load/save methods which internally just use `FileGet` and `FilePut`.  Doing so would be good practice anyway.  That way, if you ever choose to store the data in a different format, or a different data source (such as a database), you could change it in the one class without having to rewrite all of your code.

Comment: Few things comes me to mind at first reading. It isn't smart (or useful) to store data in database if those data contain parameters to access to database (like username, pass and so.) Second, what you call "backward compatibility" shouldn't be called that way because this is not any backward compatibility but it is "certain way of disk access" which all normal programming languages have. OK, nowdays fixed length strings lacks in most cases (unicode) but after all I can conclude that "they do not do all what was needed to do"! In that case Microsoft.VisualBasic is good choice then.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing I've just found is this MSDN page about My.Computer.FileSystem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b485hf7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

which I found was referred to from the MSDN page on FilePut:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s9sa1ab%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

From posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871214/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-my-computer-filesystem-and-system-io-file)   It's my understanding that it's just a wrapper for System.IO anyway, but it supposedly provides a "more convenient and understandable" interface to the underlying IO functions.

Comment: almost ALL the VB namespace, and certainly the compatibility layer is just a wrapper for underlying NET operations. "convenient and understandable" are subjective

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to your use of the LEN() function (which is the only thing I can see that refers to Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, unless I'm missing something), then you can just use String.Length instead.  E.g. idstruct.Length, assuming idstruct is a String.

Comment: `Freefile`, `FileOpen`, `FilePut` and `FileClose` are all from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem`

Comment: `LEN` [returns an integer containing either the number of characters in a string or the nominal number of bytes required to store a variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx), so `String.Length` is *not* a valid replacement.

Comment: Guess I was totally out of my element here.  What can I say, programmers can be arrogant sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `System.IO.FileStream`.  The approach is a bit different, but it is quite simple.

```
 Dim fs As New FileStream(mUserFile, FileMode.XXX, FileAccess.XXX)
```

or:

```
 Using fs as New FileStream....

 End Using
```

The main thing that will change is that rather than writing a structure, you would convert it to an array of bytes (Count would be the length of your array, offset 0 in your example):

```
 fs.Write(byt(), lOffset, lCount)
```

You COULD wrap it all up in a class to emulate the old random access file method if there it a lot of legacy code to support. There is also a `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` and you could also look into serialization if the data is large but mostly static.

Comment: Well, I can always read a file like bytearray then do conversions according to my struct's or read elements one by one by adding an offset but those workarounds is exactly what I try to avoid.

Comment: The original question simply asked about the NET equiv for the legacy VB file IO functions and didnt mention compatibility with QB.  With THAT now revealed, I probably would not bother converting t NET and certain things like XML and serialization are especially unsuitable.

Comment: It's OK, If I will know answer to my question I would not ask it. Keep Microsoft.Visual basic is probably most cheap solution im that case.