# VB.NET throws System.IO.IOException unsupported when trying to overwrite file

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in my application:

`My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("D:\Temp\Origin.log", "D:\Temp\Destination.log", True)`

This code used to work fine until 1 or 2 months ago.

The last couple of months it fails to execute and it throws a 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll "Unsupported" when the destination files exists.

My target framework is 4.7.2

I tried to change target framework to 4.6.2 in case an update of NET framework broke it, but still I have the same issue.

Right now I had to temporarily bypass the problem like this:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("D:\Temp\Destination.log") Then
      My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("D:\Temp\Destination.log", FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently)
End If
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("D:\Temp\Origin.log", "D:\Temp\Destination.log", True)
```

While the above code works, it defeats the purpose of having an overwrite overload (which is still supported in 4.7.2 AFAIK)

Also it means I have to change it in far too many places inside my application code.

Does anyone knows why my original code stopped working, or better yet, how to fix it ?

Edit:
Exception Stack:

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80070032
  Message=The request is not supported.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyOrMoveFile(CopyOrMove operation, String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite, UIOptionInternal showUI, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.CopyFile(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at KT_Scan_Docs_Manager.Frm_Main.CreateFilelist(Int32 Meleti) in C:\Users\GTsag\Dropbox\Visual Studio\KT2-14 Scan Docs Manager\KT2-14 Scan Docs Manager\frm_Main.vb:line 2880
   at KT_Scan_Docs_Manager.Frm_Main.Bt_KT214CreateFileList_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\GTsag\Dropbox\Visual Studio\KT2-14 Scan Docs Manager\KT2-14 Scan Docs Manager\frm_Main.vb:line 148
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at KT_Scan_Docs_Manager.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
```

Comment: Does `IO.File.Copy("D:\Temp\Origin.log", "D:\Temp\Destination.log", True)` have the same problem?

Comment: Might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871214/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-my-computer-filesystem-and-system-io-file) useful.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes it has the exact same problem

Comment: @PhantomDj Can you add the whole error stack trace to the question? I am wondering if it is a related to [NotSupportedException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception) which makes me wonder if somehow you have an old version of mscorlib.dll. Or if the filesystem of D: was changed from when it was working.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Filesystem is and was NTFS. Nothing fancy there.
As for the stack I'll have to switch my OS language to get you one ASAP.
I noticed a few more misbehaviors with my app BTW. Generally speaking it's as if my app is not allowed to overwrite anything (but still able to delete and create files)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Added stack at original post

Comment: @PhantomDj Have you [run sfc.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) in case there is a problem with Windows? Does your program have anything to do with scheduled tasks - I found a few mentions of that when searching for "0x80070032".

Comment: sfc didn't find any integrity violations.
Also the app has nothing to do with scheduled tasks.
I use it once every month to perform some tasks with files.
It has been working fine for about 2 years, until last month, on the exact same environment. That's why I suspect that it must have something to do with a recent .NET update

Comment: Have you tried running the program as Administrator? Does the misbehaving only happen on drive D: ?

Comment: Yes, I tried as run as Administrator, it made no difference. Also it fails to overwrite anyhting.
Another thing: My app also opens around 100 MDB files to read stuff.
After reading each mdb file it closes and disposes connection.
However LDB files remain active until the app is done working.
This was not an issue before, but at the same time overwrite stopped working, I found out that my app threw exceptions when 36 LDB files were present.
I solved that issue, but all my problems started around the same time about one month ago...